# Update Ranking Points Based on Date Range

Tags: mysql

Currently, I am building a personal project.

1. A site that stores Racing Information and grants point to weekly individual winners.
2. These racers have groups and points earned by the group will be ranked on a monthly basis.

The query below returns Top racing information of the current week where the current week starts every Tuesday.

```
SELECT *
FROM timeatk 
WHERE DATE(posted)
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
        AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
ORDER BY timer ASC LIMIT 0, 10
```

But, I am working on a CRON, where a PHP script should be triggered depending on the date on a for-loop. Coz' every Tuesday, I need to add points for the weekly winners.

**For the weekly results:**

I would like to UPDATE the weekly top ten racers based on the lowest time on the "timer" column **from** the last week's Tuesday until Monday of the current week.

**Weekly Winners:**

- 1st = 10points
- 2nd = 9points
- 3rd = 8points
- .. until
- 10th = 1point

```
for ($score = 10; $score > 0; $score--) {
        $data = [
            'score' => $score
        ];
        $sql = "update ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list set weekly_score = :score where DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)";
        $stmt= $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `timeatk_has_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `racer_has_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `racer_has_mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `racer_has_nationality` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `racer_has_email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `motor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `gear_ratio` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `chassis` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `timer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `posted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `weekly_score` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[image]

*Here's a simple SELECT query to check the result.*

The UPDATE query above updates ALL rows weekly_score with 1.

***And here's the working SQL query with the help of J.D:***

```
UPDATE timeatk_has_list
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by timer desc) AS RacerRank
        FROM timeatk_has_list
        WHERE DATE(posted)
            BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
            AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
        ORDER BY timer ASC LIMIT 0, 10
) c
    ON ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list.id = c.id
SET ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list.weekly_score = 11 - c.RacerRank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always include your schema and sample before and after data, otherwise it's difficult to conceptualize what we don't know.

You can solve this pretty easily without even using a loop in PHP, rather by using a **window function** in MySQL like [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) to generate the ranks and then use those ranks to update your scores. Here's a partial example (if you update your question with the missing items I mentioned above, I can update this example):

```
UPDATE ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list
INNER JOIN 
(
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timer DESC) AS RacerRank -- Generates a unique ID (assuming timer is unique) for each racer row ordered by timer
        FROM timeatk 
        WHERE DATE(posted)
            BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(now()), INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
            AND DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 6 - (WEEKDAY(now()) - 1 + 7) % 7 DAY)
        ORDER BY timer ASC LIMIT 0, 10
) c -- Gets the racer rank
    ON ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list.id = c.id -- Fill in your actual key fields here
SET ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list.weekly_score = 11 - c.RacerRank -- Sets the weekly score to 10 for 1st place, 9 for 2nd place, etc
```

Comment: Hi J.D. I have already updated my post and added the table structure. Currently, I only have Xampp 7.3 and it does not support CTEs. It's actually my first time using ROW_NUMBER and even tried a PHP Array to loop the points.

Comment: Strange. I changed the t.id = c.id. But returned an error message instead.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE t
SET t.weekly_score = 11 - c.RacerRank
FROM ometimeatk.timeatk_has_l...' at line 11

Comment: @Romanov **Xampp** is unrelated to what database features you have available, but maybe your implementation and version of MySQL is lacking **CTEs**. Could you please provide that information as well? Also `JOIN` might not be available in `UPDATE` statements for the same reason. I'll re-write my answer when I get a chance today to give you an alternative to these things that should work (e.g. a **subquery** instead of the **CTE** should work just the same logically).

Comment: @Romanov I've updated my answer to something more compatible with your version of MySQL by replacing the **CTE** with a **subquery** instead. I also believe I fixed the syntax for the `UPDATE` statement, but am unable to test on my end. Please let me know if this works for you or if you run into any other issues, and I'll fix it accordingly.

Comment: Hi J.D. Thanks for the updated query. It worked now. I just removed the db_name from the Update ometimeatk.timeatk_has_list and added ORDER BY clause for the Row_number(). I have updated my question with the working SQL query. This SQL query will be added together with the CRON JOB to run every week. Thank you!

Comment: Update. For the RacerRank. I updated the query to this: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by timer desc). Currently, it adds a point in increasing order. So the lowest/fastest timer gets 1point which is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. Would it be okay to add "ORDER BY TIMER DESC"?

Comment: @Romanov Yes sorry that was a typo, I've updated my answer to reflect that as well. That is correct. Glad it worked out for you! Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer so other users with similar questions see it verified as helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help J.D. I have accepted your answer but I couldn't upvote with my current reputation. I've learned about ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Romanov No problem and thanks! I'm glad you learned something. You should research "**window functions**" in MySQL further, they're very helpful. There are other ones out there. :)